# Merge, chunk, then transpose and flatten data from multiple indexed arrays

Tags: php, arrays, merge, transpose, chunks

I have three arrays:

```
$a = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'a7', 'a8', 'a9', 'a10'];
$b = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'b7', 'b8', 'b9', 'b10'];
$c = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'c7', 'c8', 'c9', 'c10'];
```

I want to combine these arrays to create:

```
$new1 = (a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2);

$new2 = (a3, a4, b3, b4, c3, c4);

$new3 = (a5, a6, b5, b6, c5, c6);

$new4 = (a7, a8, b7, b8, c7, c8);

$new5 = (a9, a10, b9, b10, c9, c10);
```

How to make it like that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what does this have to do with `laravel`?

Comment: Sorry for the `Laravel` tags not included

Comment: We need to see the related PHP code so we can try to determine where your error is. Please edit your question to include the code. (thx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You, you would want to map each array into it's chunked version using `array_map` and `array_chunk`, so that you get them in 2 element arrays.  Then, you would want to reduce those so that each chunk goes in the same final array, for which you would use `array_reduce`:

```
$a = array('a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'a7', 'a8', 'a9', 'a10');
$b = array('b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'b7', 'b8', 'b9', 'b10');
$c = array('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'c7', 'c8', 'c9', 'c10');

$final = array_reduce(array_map(function($el) {
             return array_chunk($el, 2);
         }, [$a, $b, $c]), function($carry, $item) {
             foreach($item as $key => $value) {
                 if (!isset($carry[$key])) {
                     $carry[$key] = [];
                 }
                 $carry[$key] = array_merge($carry[$key], $value);
             }
             return $carry;
         });

$new1 = $f[0];
$new2 = $f[1];
$new3 = $f[2];
$new4 = $f[3];
$new5 = $f[4];

var_dump($f);
/*
 array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "a1"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "a2"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "b1"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "b2"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "c1"
    [5]=>
    string(2) "c2"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "a3"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "a4"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "b3"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "b4"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "c3"
    [5]=>
    string(2) "c4"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "a5"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "a6"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "b5"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "b6"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "c5"
    [5]=>
    string(2) "c6"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "a7"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "a8"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "b7"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "b8"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "c7"
    [5]=>
    string(2) "c8"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "a9"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "a10"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "b9"
    [3]=>
    string(3) "b10"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "c9"
    [5]=>
    string(3) "c10"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add all array in one array

1. Then applied while loop with count of `$a/2`
2. Then use `array_map` return with iterated index value plus one .its means if is `0` its get `a1,a2` value  respectively .
3. Then finally merge array and pass with result array

[**Sandbox Test**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/674396c56177dc9b1336b4f554fe3aa2287a9183)

```
$a = Array('a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'a7', 'a8', 'a9', 'a10');
$b = Array('b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'b7', 'b8', 'b9', 'b10');
$c = Array('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'c7', 'c8', 'c9', 'c10');
$arr = [$a,$b,$c];
$i=0;
$res=[];
while($i < (count($a)/2)){
    $res[$i]=call_user_func_array('array_merge',array_map(function($ar=[]) use ($i){
       return [$ar[$i],$ar[$i+1]];
    },$arr));
    $i++;
}
print_r($res);
print_r($res[0]);
$new1=$res[0];
$new2=$res[1];
$new3=$res[2];

print_r($new1);
print_r($new2);
print_r($new3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fully functional-style approach that will accept any number of arrays.  It is assumed that your input arrays will have the same length.  Because my approach is so flexible, it does not produce hardcoded, individual variables as its result.

1. Form a single array from all input arrays, then
2. Chunk each input array's data, then
3. Transpose and flatten the chunks.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/UViRS))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn(...$cols) => array_merge(...$cols),
        ...array_map(
            fn($row) => array_chunk($row, 2),
            [$a, $b, $c]
        )
    )
);
```